# Reading potentiometer value in high voltage circuit externally

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, resistance, high-voltage, potentiometer

I want to be able to read the value of a potentiometer in an existing high-voltage circuit externally with a microcontroller, but am concerned how the existing circuit would affect the Arduino and conversely how the Arduino could affect the existing circuit.

Here is my first idea for how a circuit could be constructed to measure potentiometer value in an already existing circuit:

[image: Potential circuit featuring Arduino wired to potentiometer with no supplementary components.]

My worry with this circuit is that the voltage going into the potentiometer from the already existing circuit would get shorted through the Arduino, frying it in the process.

My next idea was the addition of a diode to assure voltage would go across the potentiometer and not short through Arduino itself, but I still worry in such a circuit that the 5V supplied by the Arduino would get boosted depending on voltage across the potentiometer, frying the Arduino as well.

[image: Same circuit with a diode attached to 5V from arduino.]

Will either of these circuits would work or is there a better way of going about measuring the value of a potentiometer in a given circuit externally?

Comment: Both of those circuits would fairly immediately burn your Arduino. So, instead of showing circuits that won't work (in the hope that they impart something useful to the reader), please explain what you are trying to do more technically.

Comment: Thought I was pretty clear in stating that I wanted a way of measuring the value of a potentiometer that is already in a circuit with a microcontroller. If you're asking me to explain why I want to do this so that alternatives can be suggested, then I'm not interested. Point of making this specific thread was to inquire if such a circuit was possible.

Comment: You have 40 V going to the 5 V pin on your Arduino. It won't survive that.

Comment: If you want to measure the value of a potentiometer, one way is to read the wiper voltage AND the voltage on the non-grounded end of the potentiometer. To do both these things effectively (and without detonating the Arduino), more details are needed so that the necessary extra resistor values can be calculated. Maybe you are trying only to read the wiper voltage but, that is contrary to "measuring the value of the potentiometer". So, no, I don't believe you have been very clear so far.

Comment: Neither of your circuits will work. If you want a better way, then we need more information.

Comment: But you are not being very clear in what you want, as Andy points out.  High voltage?  40V going to 5V.  Is high voltage 40V?  What is going to prevent wiper to go to high voltage?  40V will fry Arduino.  You don't measure potentiometer, you measure voltage.

Comment: use a dual gang potentiometer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what you want to do is measure the voltage at the wiper of a potentiometer that is connected to 40 VDC with an ADC that has an input range of 0 to 5 VDC what you need to do is reduce the voltage from the pot to what your ADC can handle.

You can do that in this case with a simple resistive voltage divider.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3TvIE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For a 10:1 divider you want 1 part out of 10, so if the value of R3 is 10k you need a total of 100k between R2 and R3, or put another way, make R2 9 times the value of R3. This give you a range of 0 to 4 V to the ADC, if you want the full ADC range of 0 to 5 V you can adjust the divider values a bit so that 40 V in gives 5 V out, and then have your software deal with that.

A resistive divider does affect, and is affected by the rest of the circuit, the divider loads down the potentiometer, and the ADC loads down the divider. The higher the value of the pot, the higher the values in the divider need to be, and the lower the input impedance of the ADC the lower the divider values need to be. It's a trade off at best, and at worst you need to do some buffering with opamps. If there is the possibility of voltage spikes higher than 50 V on the voltage feeding the pot you also need to have some way to protect the ADC input from excess voltage.

Comment: This seems like a good solution. The potentiometer does not need to be polled frequently so briefly diverting voltage through a divider circuit like this just to get a reading seems like a good approach. Marking as solved.